# Reading binary data C (open, read)

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read a png file with `read()` and `open()` in C, but all I'm getting is corrupted data. Here is my code :

```
int  r;
int  fd;
char buff[4097];

fd = open("image.png", O_RDONLY);
while ((r = read(fd, buff, 4096)) > 0)
{
    buff[r] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buff);
}
close(fd);
```

The 8-10 first bytes are the same and then the data is corrupted and doesn't match at all the original image.
Thanks for your help

Comment: How does this data not "match at all the original image"? Are you aware that (1) in a PNG image, the image data may not follow immediately after the header, and (2) it is LZW compressed? In other words, are you aware there is a [PNG Format Specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html)?

Comment: Well, you are reading some binary data and try to print it with "%s" so if, for example, there is null character(0x00) in your image data you will not see the data after that character. So, it is perfectly normal that you don't get a matching result.

Comment: Okay I see! Yes I'm aware of PNG specification, I'm handling this later in my code, first I'm just trying to get the binary data in order to process it.

Answer (score 3):

One should not expect to be able to read a binary file and print it as a string. In order to see what is actually in your file, print it as something more suitable for the binary format - say, hex:

```
int i = 0;
while ((r = read(fd, buff, 4096)) > 0) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j != r ; j++ ) {
        printf("%02x ", buff[j]);
        if (i % 16 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        i++;
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Note that this code simply grabs raw bytes from your image file, without making any attempt at interpreting it. Your file may be compressed, too, so trying to interpret it may be a complex task.

Comment: And the image data in a PNG file in particular is *always* compressed.